# Error converting nvarchar to bigint in WHERE clause fails but works in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, casting, sql-server-2019

I am trying to achieve the following:

> Get all Field values where the `FieldValue` is **greater than 100** when the
> value is stored as a number.

The indicator of whether or not if a value was stored as a number is given by the field type, which is another where clause.

The issue I am facing is that when I try to do the data field conversion in my WHERE statement, it failed.

I run:

```
SELECT FieldValue FROM CARData A
JOIN Fields B ON A.FieldId = B.FieldId
WHERE FieldTypeId = 3 AND FieldValue IS NOT NULL
```

And this returns the expected result of:

[image: Result]

But if I added the WHERE clause to filter by the value:

```
SELECT FieldValue FROM CARData A
JOIN Fields B ON A.FieldId = B.FieldId
WHERE FieldTypeId = 3 AND FieldValue IS NOT NULL 
AND CAST(FieldValue AS BIGINT) > 100
```

It throws the error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

I somewhat understand what the issue is- it is trying to convert ALL values in the table to a bigint and is failing when it hits a non-numeric value.

I attempted to solve this by nesting the first query in a second like so:

```
SELECT RESULT.FieldValue FROM (
SELECT FieldValue FROM CARData A
JOIn Fields B ON A.FieldId = B.FieldId
WHERE 
FieldTypeId = 3 
AND FieldValue IS NOT NULL 
AND ISNUMERIC(A.FieldValue) = 1) RESULT
WHERE CAST(FieldValue AS BIGINT) > 100
```

But even that does not return anything other than the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's true that changing the structure of your query can cause SQL to pick a different plan, you should limit that technique to trying to help the optimizer pick a performant plan. The reason for this is that if successful execution of the logic depends on a particular choice of plan, then your query might work today but fail tomorrow (or in production) when SQL decides to pick a different plan.

Fortunately you don't have to rely on that here! Use [try_cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT FieldValue FROM CARData A
JOIN Fields B ON A.FieldId = B.FieldId
WHERE FieldTypeId = 3 
AND TRY_CAST(FieldValue AS BIGINT) > 100
```

I'm also curious... is this part of a SQL course? If so, tell your instructor to come visit StackOverflow so we can tell them to stop teaching students to use EAV's. Unless the whole point is to show you how horrible they are! :)

Comment: Before `TRY_CAST` you could use a `CASE` expression to force short circuiting.

Comment: Nope, not a learning course! It's an issue I am looking at in an EFCore query so I ended up translating it translating SQL queries and then broke it into a simple question of what's actually happening in the query; which happens to end up looking like a SQL Course Question :P 
I unfortunately had to settle for an EAV table since the data stored here is that of a dynamic form system.  I could probably rewrite it to store each value in an appropriately typed column... Either way, thank you, your solution works!

Comment: Hey @AaronBertrand, thanks for the comment. Can you please expand on that a bit? Are you suggesting placing the `TRY_CAST` in a `CASE` that checks `ISNUMERIC` first?

Comment: @Bitz No, I'm saying that if you were on an ancient, unsupported version of SQL Server before `TRY_CAST` existed, you could use a `CASE` expression. (And I never said anything about `ISNUMERIC`.)

Comment: @Bitz Don't touch `ISNUMERIC` with a barge pole, it's broken in so many ways `ISNUMERIC(-.)` returns 1

Comment: @AaronBertrand, Ah thanks! I will include the minimum SQL Server version in future questions. I have updated this question as such too!
Charlieface, Thanks for the warning, I will avoid it!